# How do I reset password for AD4J?

Tags: oracle

I installed oracle's AD4J sometime back and seem to have forgot the password. Not able to figure out how to reset the password for it. Please don't hate me for this :(

Answer (score 1):

See the [AD4J Console Administration Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B16240_01/doc/admin.102/e11084/chapter1.htm).  The [Console Setup Page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B16240_01/doc/admin.102/e11084/chapter1.htm#insertedID7) is where you would reset a password.  That page doesn't require the old password, but I honestly can't tell if you can access that page without logging in.  (Since it's a setup page, you might be able to.)

[alt text http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B16240_01/doc/admin.102/e11084/img/console_setup_page.gif](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B16240_01/doc/admin.102/e11084/img/console_setup_page.gif)

Comment: No couldn't get in without a password. Hard luck for me.